# JavaFx - Closing a Tab in TabPane doesn't release memory

Tags: memory-management, memory-leaks, javafx-8

The problem is that when an old tab is removed, it does not seem to be garbage collected.

here is a simple example

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
    stage.setTitle("Tabs example");

    // create window holder        
    final TabPane tabPane = new TabPane();
    tabPane.setSide(Side.BOTTOM);
    tabPane.setTabClosingPolicy(TabPane.TabClosingPolicy.SELECTED_TAB);    
    tabPane.getTabs().add(new Tab("First Tab"));

    // create buttons
    Button add = new Button("Add Tab");
    Button remove = new Button("Remove Tab");


    HBox hBox = new HBox(8);       
    hBox.getChildren().add(add);
    hBox.getChildren().add(remove);

    add.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent t) {
            tabPane.getTabs().add(new Tab("New Tab"));
        }
    });

    remove.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

        @Override
        public void handle(ActionEvent t) {                
            if (!tabPane.getSelectionModel().isEmpty()){
                tabPane.getTabs().remove(tabPane.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex());
            }
        }
    });        


    BorderPane borderPane = new BorderPane();
    borderPane.setCenter(tabPane);
    borderPane.setTop(hBox);

    // add components to screen
    Group root = new Group();
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);

    borderPane.setPrefSize(500, 500);

    root.getChildren().add(borderPane);        
    stage.setScene(scene);        
    stage.centerOnScreen();
    stage.show();
}
```

Question is: Am I suppose to do something more, other than remove(), when I decide to close a tab? Or is this just a memory leak?

Thank you,

Comment: That's just not how the garbage collector in Java works. The memory will be deallocated when the garbage collector detects a need to run, which is going to be at some arbitrary point in the future. As long as you don't retain references to objects, they will be eligible for garbage collection, but that doesn't mean they will be garbage collected immediately.

Comment: Thank you @James_D for your response. can you explain to me why garbage collection doesn't happen even with an explicit System.gc() call